# How do we test after upgrading to 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.12 (any possible testing commands to know the configuration works after upgrade?)?

Tags: openssl

How do we test  after upgrading to 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.12 (any possible testing commands to know the configuration is working right after upgrade)?

Also note i had to reboot server after reboot:

when tried to login via ssh after upgrade got message:

```
System restart required
```

Answer (score 0):

SSLlabs tests for Heartbleed:

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Answer (score 0):

This one is probably the most used one:

http://filippo.io/Heartbleed/